# What kind of cable for AUX should I use?

Tags: amplifier, cable, aux-sends

my room is under renovation and I'd like to hide all the wires of my hi-fi set under the floor.
I have to choose cable to connect laptops out with amps aux in - it would be over 6 meters long.
Would microphone cable be suitable? Due to it is stereo and has shield better than in one I can buy i local electronics store. I'd like to get rid of all the fuzz getting from the air by not shielded wires.
[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microphone cable is *not* stereo but symmetric.  However, your laptop output is *asymmetric* and stereo.  What does that mean if you abuse microphone cable in that manner?  Basically high crosstalk and substandard shielding against noise and hum.  You are better off using some stock cinch stereo cable.

Comment: So one like Proel HPC300 would be ok? http://www.proel.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=5848